# Where's the width() function in jQuery source?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Where's the `width()` function in [jQuery source](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js)?

Comment: @Felix Kling: I searched myself, but I'm not used to such signature as `each([]` for declaring functions.

Comment: Ok, I can understand that. As I said, it is just how you phrased the question. Or maybe I just should get some sleep ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Search for `jQuery.each([ "Height", "Width" ], function( i, name ) {` in the code (around the end of the file).

The function is defined by the following statement, when name = "Width" in the outer function.

```
jQuery.fn[ type ] = function( size ) {
```

Comment: Thanks! So, the function is defined in runtime, just when I call it?

Comment: @Tom Brito: No, the function is defined when the jQuery is loaded. You could say it is dynamically defined but the `jQuery.each` above is executed when the code is loaded, not when you call the function.

Comment: @Tom: You'll notice that 6 methods are being generated. `outerWidth outerHeight innerWidth innerHeight width height` jQuery does this a lot to generate functions that have some code in common. Instead of reusing code by having the functions call another function, the reuse it by dynamically generating the functions in a loop. Whatever tweaks are required to make the functions unique are less expensive than an actual shared function invocation.

Answer (score 6):

A convenient way to browse the jQuery source is using James Padolsey's interactive [source viewer](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/) (<strike>unfortunately down as of this writing</strike> Update: Working again).

Answer (score 0):

Actually the last  function in the chain which is called for width calculation : `getWidthOrHeight`

At least in latest jquery code:

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js